# Using transform and element positioning/size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure if this is really solvable/possible but...

I'm trying to implement a particular animation where my screen is divided in 2 vertically on the first page, but after doing some sort of event (wheel, scroll, click, etc), the layout will animate smoothly to divide the screen horizontally.

If you hover over the first example, I tried to just rotate both inner elements, and then tried to resize the elements based on the new, rotated position. This did not work well.

As you can see, as the elements rotate, there are several issues:

1. They don't rotate perfectly in sync
2. You can see the ugly whitespace of the container behind it as it rotates
3. After rotating, the elements do not fill the container perfectly

I have tried many different things, like using z-index, absolute positioning, tried putting the inner elements in another nested container and then rotating the container, then adding height and width, but again the sizes didn't fit the container. I cannot seem to figure out how to make this work (without Javscript, if possible).

Essentially, the animation I have in mind would make the transition from the Initial Stage to the Final Stage seamless (ie. You wouldn't be able to see the whitespace in the background of the container, and the starting vertical line of separation would just slowly rotate to a horizontal line, while changing the position of the inner elements)

I hope this makes sense? I've been trying to get this animation to work for days...and I am exhausted of options/not creative enough/don't have the knowledge I need; help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 5% auto;
 
}

.container:hover .left {
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 100%;
}
.container:hover .right {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 2s;

}

.right {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%; 
  transition: all 2s;
}

  
.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 5% auto;
}


.left2 {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.right2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
Initial Stage
<p>(width of the container is the viewport; I don't care about if the element extends outside of the viewport during the transtion, but at the final stage, the element must be within it's container perfectly)</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

Final Stage
<p>(width of the container is the viewport; I don't care about if the element extends outside of the viewport during the transtion, but at the final stage, the element must be within it's container perfectly)</p>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="left2">
    I have content in here that I need fit within this container
  </div>
  <div class="right2">
    I have content in here that I need fit within this container
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to just match the width & height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding transition to left/ right divs add it to the container div

```
 .container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 5% auto;
   transition: all 2s;
   transform: rotate(0deg);

}
.container:hover { 
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also Remove transitions and transforms from left right divs

Comment: Updated answer please check now